# Picasso: adding multiple images dynamically in flipper for Android.

Tags: android, image, firebase, picasso

I'm new to picasso.using it i want to dynamically fetch images and be able to update the images whenever some new link has been updated. currently i'm only able to do this for a single Image. the code that i'm using is :

```
picasso.with(this).load(url).into(image1)
```

where url is  the url to the image and image1 is an imageview. i want to diaplay 5 images into 5 different imageviews, iteratively. how can i do that ?
also i wan to delete the cached images of picasso, so that i can update it with newer images. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your xml just add only this,

```
<ViewFlipper 
android:id="@+id/flipper" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"> 
</ViewFlipper>
```

lets Say your URL Images Array like this.

```
String ImgAry[] = {"url1","url2","url3","url4","url5"}
```

In your onCreate()

```
 viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flipper);
     for(int i=0;i<ImgAry.length;i++)
            {
            // create dynamic image view and add them to ViewFlipper
                setImageInFlipr(ImgAry[i]);
            }
```

method in Your Activity file

```
private void setImageInFlipr(String imgUrl) {

    ImageView image = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
    picasso.with(this).load(imgUrl).into(image);
    viewFlipper.addView(image);
}
```

Comment: how do i delete the cached images ? if i want to ? @rjz Satvara

Comment: just use this line for no Cache...

picasso.with(this).load(imgUrl).memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE).into(image);

Comment: i did just that but it says we cant override the existing image in the imageview!!

Answer (score 0):

```
private void setImageInFlipr(String imgUrl) {

    ImageView image = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
    picasso.get().load(imgUrl).into(image);
    viewFlipper.addView(image);
}
```

Comment: Hope It will solve issue but please add explaination of your code with it so user will get perfect understanding which he/she really wants